# How to convert a unicode character "\U0001d403" to Escape sequence in python?

Tags: python, decode, encode, python-unicode, unicode-escapes

It is a Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols ( capital D ) and I just want to convert into simple English letter ( Capital D ).

Like, `\U0001d403` => `\uxxxx`.

I am not familiar with decode-encoding mechanism.

Is there any conversion way ?

Comment: Could you maybe further clarify your question. since running  `print('\U0001d403')` gives the Capital D

Comment: The escape sequence is only useful in string *literals*. If you already have a `str` value, you probably just want a new string with the correct character already in it.

Comment: If you are looking for a way to convert this symbol into a normal capital D, you can do `import unicodedata` and then `unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', '\U0001d403')` results in `'D'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing else, you can build your own map for the string translation: for example:

```
>>> x = '\U0001d403'
>>> x
''
>>> x.translate(str.maketrans({'\U0001d403': 'D'}))
'D'
```

`maketrans` can create a mapping of multiple characters, which can be saved to be reused as an argument for many calls to `str.translate`. Note also that `str.translate` works for arbitrary strings; the given map will be applied to each character separately.